# About the speed of neutrino

Tags: mass, speed-of-light, neutrinos

1. Does the neutrino have  a charge?
2. and how does it travel at speed of light although it is known that it has mass because it has antineutrino?

Comment: Maybe you should first read the relevant Wikipedia article about the "neutrino".

Comment: it used to be thought, and you will find in old books, that the neutrino was massless. Neutrino oscilations showed that they do have a mass, though very small.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation

Answer (score 2):

Neutrinos have no charge, and because they have mass, they do *not* travel at the speed of light. Because their mass is exceedingly tiny, however, neutrinos tend to be very, very relativistic, and hence tend to travel very close to the speed of light.

As an aside, the existence of antineutrinos does *not* imply that neutrinos have mass. In fact, the [Standard Model of Particle Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) contains antineutrinos but does not account for neutrino masses. Instead, the evidence that neutrinos must be massive comes from observation of [neutrino oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation), where one flavor of neutrino will oscillate into another flavor.

Comment: Chris, I rolled back your editings of the question. It is rude to non english speaking people to change  drastically the content.

Comment: In the standard model the neutrinos are massless and the particle or anti-particle nature is identified with the chirality only. Given that we know there is mass we're into 'beyond the standard model' physics. It is a open question whether neutrinos are Dirac (and have distinct anti-particles) or Majorana (and don't). Experiments are underway that should answer the question, but it's going to be a while yet before we have definitive results from them.